# How can I make the minitoc show details only for the current chapter/part?

Tags: table-of-contents, htlatex, minitoc

I have a rather large online textbook with four levels (from part to subsection) and about 50 to 70 elements in the toc. All of them are shown in the minitoc on the left side. This makes it very uneasy to read. I would like to have in the minitoc only the top level entries (part) and for the one part in which I'm reading a page to show all entries. Is that possible, and how?
Best,

Christian

Comment: Welcome. You can modify the counters `tocdepth` and `minitocdepth`. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348278/minitoc-does-not-print-the-same-depth-as-global-toc

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I want. I'll try to be more specific. If I view a page in part 3, I'd like the toc to show: Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, Chapter 3.1, Section 3.1.1, Sec, 3.1.2,Chapter 3.2, Sec. 3.2.1, Sec. 3.2.2, Part 4, Part 5... So the details only for the chapter I'm currently reading. If I go to a page in Part 1 (e.g. with a link) then the toc should show details of Part 1, but not of Part 3 anymore.

Comment: can you please show us a minimal example of your code?

Comment: How is this connected to `htlatex`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer hello :-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317686/trouble-building-a-site-with-frames-using-tex4ht